# Get users email address, where the script is run as "Me"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I've got a Google apps script project running on a Google site. The site requires users to sign in, and it only open to users on this G-suite domain.

The scripts I have are for allowing users to do voting, get into a queue of speakers, and some other tasks.

Currently all the functions in the background would work fine running as "Me" which I prefer, however I need to know the e-mail address of the user running the script (viewing the Google site).
Is there any way for me to get the e-mail address of the signed in user viewing the page that is running the script, while running the actual script as me?

If not, can I have one script run as the user, then call another script that runs as me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to indentify user using google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172849/how-to-indentify-user-using-google-apps-script)

Comment: How did you solve it in the end?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Classic Google sites is shut down. So, how are you running apps script in new Google sites?

Comment: @TheMaster you embed them in page.

Comment: This is being discussed [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256574/room-for-barry-the-platipus-and-themaster)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64355436/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911167/

Answer (score 19):

have you tried logging these?  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

```js
 // Log the email address of the user under whose authority the script is running.
 var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
 Logger.log(email);
```

```js
 // Log the email address of the person running the script.
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 Logger.log(email);
```

Comment: That is what I'm using to get the e-mail, but it only gets the e-mail of the user running the script. So I have to then have the script run as the user.  I'd prefer to run the script as myself or a service account, because when run as the user, then I need to have the docs/sheets the script accesses set to be shared with that user.   If I ran it as myself, and was able to get the users e-mail address somehow, I could avoid having to set those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the web app as "Execute as me" . In the "who has access" field, select "Anyone with Google account". In the script, get the user's email using `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`