# Is there a script function to get user email when they edit a cell in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some difficulty searching and creating a script. What I am trying to achieve is getting the user's email/name when they edited a cell in my spreadsheet. I tried getactiveuser but its not showing anything. I read that some ask to use geteffectiveuser but all I get is still my username back and not the other editor.

Here is my script so far:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "TEST" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column for HUB side
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(email());
    }
  }
}

Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
```

As of the above, nothing is showing up.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user. I think you need `getActiveUser().getEmail()`

Comment: function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "TEST" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(email());
    }
    
  }
}

Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

Yes sir, this is my script but nothing is showing up. is there any workaround to this?

Comment: You may post the code in your question panel, so that others can see what is the problem.

Comment: Done and updated sir

Answer (score 1):

You may perform a test on the following code, it work for me :)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "TEST" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = e.range;
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column for HUB side
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi its working for me the owner but its not working for other users.

Comment: Try this and see? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848448/google-apps-script-get-users-email-address. I cannot test it alone `var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()`

Comment: The `Onedit(e)` cannot return email address other than the developer himself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356262/how-can-i-get-email-of-the-last-user-who-modified-each-cell