# Apps Script Making onEdit and onOpen triggers work only for the current user

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Probably the answer to this is simple but I am having a tough time getting my head around it.

I have a spreadsheet used by many users. I want custom onEdit and onOpen functions to run only for the user who triggers then. For example - if person B opens the spreadsheet, then only his custom onOpen trigger should run, not the custom onOpen triggers for the other users. Likewise if the user edits a cell only his custom onEdit should run.

Currently how I have set it up everyone has his own triggers but they all run the same script every time there is a trigger by any user, meaning the trigger runs 4x for no reason and it's slowing down the spreadsheet, and it also wastes script time usage for the other users who are not opening or editing the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate functions for each user and have code dynamically check for current user and run the function of current user only.

See here for getting current user. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172849/how-to-indentify-user-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: Not sure I follow. To do this I would have to make everything run as a web app? That would be very cumbersome. I am not sure how to check who opened the sheet. I know how to detect who is running a script - that's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the functions are the same but you just aren't wanting it to run for some users, you could use PropertiesService to store a user property to identify if it should run or not. You have to make some UI method to set the property and then you would check for the property at the beginning of each of your functions. Technically the functions would run but you could return out of them if you don't want to finish the logic.

Comment: This is academic now as I solved the issue another way. But just for the record the above solution does not help identify who triggers script to run.